# The quotient of the ring of integers by an ideal always seems to have the same structure

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Can the following be proven or does there exist a counter example:

The quotient of the ring of integers of a numnber field by an ideal is the direct sum of rings that are either isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_m$ or to $\mathbb{F}_q$, where $m$ is an integer and $q$ is the power of a prime.

I don't know if the following outline of a proof is correct. Let $Q$ be the quotient under consideration, and $q_1, \ldots, q_k$ the set of idempotents that are nozero and not the sum of other idempotents (they correspond to the elements of the form $(0,\ldots,1,\ldots,0)$ of Q. We have that $Q=Q.q_1+\ldots+Q.q_k$. Now for a certain $i$ consider the map $Q \rightarrow Q_i=q_1.Q$ that maps $q_1, \ldots, q_k$ to zero except $q_i \mapsto q_i$. The composition of the original quotient map with this map has an ideal as kernel. Either this ideal is maximal (and thus prime) and $Q_i$ is a finite field, either this ideal is not maximal and so $Q_i$ is not a field and the prime ideals of $Q_i$ determine the the prime factorization of the integer $m$.

Marc Bogaerts

Comment: is $\Bbb Z_m$ denoting a localization at a maximal ideal?

Answer (score 6):

A simple counterexample is $\mathbf Z[i]/(2)$. It has size 4, characteristic 2, is not a field, and is not a direct sum of two or more nonzero rings since it is a local ring (i.e., it has one maximal ideal) while the direct sum of two or more nonzero rings is not a local ring.

More generally, suppose for a number field $K$ there is a prime number $p$ such that the ideal $(p)$ in the integers of $K$ is divisible by a prime ideal power $\mathfrak p^r$ where $r > 1$. Then the quotient ring $\mathcal O_K/{\mathfrak p^r}$ is a counterexample: it is not a field since $r>1$ and it has characteristic $p$ since $\mathfrak p^r \mid (p)$, so if it were isomorphic to some $\mathbf Z/(m)$ then that $m$ would have to be $p$, but that would make it a field. It is not isomorphic to a direct sum of the two types of rings you put in your question since it is a local ring, and local rings never decompose as a direct sum of two or more nonzero rings. Every number field other than $\mathbf Q$ has a ramified prime $p$, and (by definition) such a prime is divisible by the square of some prime ideal, so in fact the ring of integers of *every* number field besides the rationals is a counterexample!

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware that the quotient had characteristic $p$. But does the question remain identical if I substitute $\mathbb{Z}_m$  by "a local ring of order $p^r$ (if the ramification index is $r$)", and to what extent does this uniquely define the structure of this ring (I don't know anything about finite commutative local rings)?

Comment: Let's just forget about ramification and see what happens in general. Just as $\mathbf Z/(m)$ breaks up into the direct product of the local rings $\mathbf Z/(p^{e_i})$, where $p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$ is the prime factorization of $m$, for any number field $K$ and nonzero ideal $\mathfrak a$ in $\mathcal O_K$ the finite ring $\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak a$ breaks up into the direct product of local rings $\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak p_i^{e_i}$, where $\mathfrak p_1^{e_1}\cdots \mathfrak p_k^{e_k}$ is the prime ideal factorization of $\mathfrak a$.

Comment: Any finite ring is a unique product of finite local rings. See the discussion of Artin rings in Atiyah and Macdonald's book on commutative algebra; any finite ring is an Artin ring, so the decomposition described there for Artin rings as a direct product of Artin local rings can be applied to the case of finite commutative rings.

Comment: When is the size of $\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak p^r$ equal to $p^r$, where $p$ is the prime number that $\mathfrak p$ lies over? For any nonzero prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ and any $r \geq 1$, the general formula for the order of that ring is $p^{fr}$, where $f = f(\mathfrak p|p)$ is the residue field degree of $\mathfrak p$ over $p$. Therefore the order of that ring is $p^r$ if and only if $f = 1$, meaning that $\mathcal O_K/\mathfrak p$ has order $p$ (rather than order some higher power of $p$).